# I need help assigning names to an entire column

Tags: excel, vba

I need help assigning names to an entire column.

```
Dim x, y, r As Integer 'x is customer , y is rows

For x = 1 To 25
For y = 2 To 102 Step 4


 ActiveWorkbook.NAmes.Add Name:="Name" & x, RefersToR1C1:="='Main '!RyC4"

Next y
Next x
```

I want my results to be : 
the names of each cell , not cell contents ***

row 2 , col 3 = Name 1

row 6 , col 3 = name 2

row 10 , col 3 = name 3

And so on ...

Comment: Can you provide a little more context here?  What is dictating the names, where are they being output, etc.  Your title is assigning a name to a column, but you are naming cell references with the body of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I'm a little lose, i think your code error is the use of the `y` and can be corrected to:

```
Dim x, y, r As Integer 'x is customer , y is rows
For x = 1 To 25
    For y = 2 To 102 Step 4
        ActiveWorkbook.NAmes.Add Name:="Name" & x, RefersToR1C1:="='Main '!R" & y & "C4"
    Next y
Next x
```

Tested code, showing the name manager:

[image]

---

After looking at it, I believe you need to fix your x loop and naming... you have overwriting names, which means you will own see D102 for each column, as shown in the image above.

Take a stab with:

```
Dim x as long, y as long, r As long 'MUST STATE "AS" FOR EACH VARIABLE, OTHERWISE THEY ARE VARIANT (X, Y, R AS INTEGER MEANS X AND Y ARE VARIANT)
r = 1
For x = 1 To 25
    For y = 2 To 102 Step 4
        ActiveWorkbook.NAmes.Add Name:="Name" & r, RefersToR1C1:="='Main '!R" & y & "C4"
        r = r+1 'this should fix all of your names to keep showing up
    Next y
Next x
```

See the now updated name manager:
[image]

---

After all of that, you still need to figure out what you are trying to do with the data... the `x` is not a problem (not really used)

Should you jsut be looking at the below?  Or maybe `x` is supposed to refer to the column component in your R1C1 (you are currently using `y` as the row).

```
Dim y As Long, r As Long ', x as long
r = 1
'for x = 1 to 25
For y = 2 To 102 Step 4
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Name" & r, RefersToR1C1:="='Main '!R" & y & "C4" 'or maybe: "='Main '!R" & y & "C" & x  ???
    r = r + 1 'this should fix all of your names to keep showing up
Next y
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed part of the problem, silly error to make. But now the issue is that its assigning name1-25 to the same cell , which is C4,R102

Comment: @MuawiyyahKhan you posted as i was in the middle of finishing my post (regarding `x` in your original code).  Hopefully that resolves all issues?  If so, please mark as Answered.